# Expansion in basis functions, which do not fulfil boundary conditions

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

I'm dealing with a (physical) problem involving the electric current on a wire, which has to vanish at its two ends (= homogeneous boundary condition). If this current is expanded in basis functions, which fulfil the boundary conditions (i.e. current vanishes at both ends), there should be no problem. If, in contrast, basis functions are used, which do not fulfil the boundary conditions (i.e. current does not vanish at both ends), one probably needs a lot of terms in a series expansion for a good approximation.

Now my question: Can a physical quantity be expanded in basis functions, which do not fulfil the boundary conditions of the physical problem? Which conditions need to be fulfilled by such a basis in order to expand a function with no error? I would highly appreciate mathematical literature or references to this issue.

Thank you very much!

Comment: This would probably be a better question for Physics:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/